# ORA-01722: invalid number while executing select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting the error

> ORA-01722: invalid number error while trying to execute "select * from
>   TABLE_X"

I tried to filter the data to find which record is causing the error.But the difficulty is what ever I tried with `Select * from the Table_x` , I get the invalid number error.

Please suggest a way to fix this error.

Comment: Is `table_x` a view maybe?

Comment: That was quick, its actually a view.

Comment: Then the view somewhere tries to convert a string to a number and that fails.

Comment: Is there any TRIGGER associated with your table?

Comment: @ShinoyShaji . . . The view is broken.  You -- or perhaps whoever wrote it -- needs to debug it.  Perhaps what happened is that data types in underlying tables changed.  But there is little you can do just by using `select *`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , yeah its the problem with the data in the underlying tables. I'm resolving it and checking for the different possibities for the issue..

Answer (score 0):

An ORA-01722 error occurs when an attempt is made to convert a character string into a number, and the string cannot be converted into a number. So somewhere along the lines, you must have tried to insert an invalid numeric value into one or more records in your table, and now it can't be selected due to it having invalid syntax like spaces between digits or disallowed non-numeric characters. Make sure you are storing numbers as integers when you are declaring data types as well.